# TFS Client Error using Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have been getting this strange error with VS2010 TFS client, whenever i try to do 
any operation related to TFS.

> Method not found: 'System.String
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.ExtendedItem.get_LockOwnerDisplayName()'

More background : I was working with TFS build services on my machine and
later I uninstalled the  TFS build services .. And after that i started getting this problem.

Also I repaired VS 2010 (Pro edition) and also re-installed VS 2010 SP1 . 
Reinstalled TFS build services, reinstalled tfs power tools also
But still the problem persists.

[image: TFS client error]
Any clue how to repair/fix this?
Any way to fix the TFS client part of VS2010 ?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Connect to TFS via code? Check out code? Compile code? Have you tried (re)installing Power Tools? Reinstall the build services and check if that works.

Comment: any operation via TFS, get latest,check out .. Yep I have reinstalled build services,power tools also.. the same error persists

Answer (score 2):

After installing the following hotfix,the problem was fixed.

[FIX: A hotfix for Visual Studio 2010 SP1 is available to add compatibility support for Visual Studio Team Foundation Service Preview](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2581206)

Intresting point from the above site :

> Note The following hotfix includes all the Team Foundation Client
>   hotfixes that were released after Visual Studio 2010 SP1 was released.

Hope this is helpful to others too.
(I guess this must have refreshed my VS2010 TFS client files)

Answer (score 1):

Another solution :
Bind and rebind the project to the TFS server.
It has solved the problem in my case.
Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

This same issue happened to me after Windows Update installed update KB2813041 to Visual Studio 2010.  After I **uninstalled** this individual update, it started working again.

Here's how to uninstall an individual update.  Go to Control Panel > Windows Update > View Update History > Installed Updates (appears in a sentence at the top of the dialog).  Then, scroll through the list of updates looking for Visual Studio and then right-click on the update you want to uninstall and click Uninstall.

Hopefully this helps somebody.

Thanks,

Andy